# Does Android have the ability to connect to a device over Bluetooth classic if already connected over BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

On iOS there is a bridging logic as mentioned below:

**This option tells the system to connect non-GATT profiles on classic Bluetooth devices, if there is a low energy GATT connection to the same device.**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbconnectperipheraloptionenabletransportbridgingkey

I am wondering if Android has something similar? For example, if I connected to my device over bluetooth classic, is there any mechanism that allows the system to connect to its BLE connection as well? Or in reverse.

Comment: Im not sure why this would be flagged to be closed, the suggested already answered question is similar but different. What I was trying to ascertain was if connecting over one bluetooth profile enables some sort of bridging to another profile (classic or ble) similar to how iOS does it.